# In Chess, are there simple "mechanics" that amateurs can learn to improve their game?

Tags: tactics, patterns

In the board game Go, for instance, it is often of great importance whether or not a stone can be captured in a so-called "ladder" (an often complicated formation). One of the things that separates professionals from beginning and intermediate players is that professionals can solve with a glance a problem that others struggle with.

Are there similar "mechanics" in chess (most likely the end game), that amateurs would do well to learn to greatly improve their game? Examples might include the ability of a king, or other piece to "catch" a passed pawn; the ability of a king to gain the opposition against the opposing king halfway across the board; the minimum number of moves needed for a bishop or knight to reach a certain critical square, etc.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Good question, and I think that there are a lot of different common patterns/tactics that improving players would do well to learn:

(very roughly ordered from simplest to most difficult)

### "Simple" tactics and endgames

- **knight forks and bishop forks** - get in the habit of just *seeing* the squares that would be forked instead of needing to spend time looking
- **rook and queen forks** - very similar to the above, but sometimes these are more difficult to see for some reason (i.e. white king on g1, knight on g3, Rg2+ would fork the two if the rook is defended)
- **king and pawn endgames** - as mentioned in your question, the [rule of square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_and_pawn_versus_king_endgame#Rule_of_the_square) is crucial.  At the end of a long variation leading into a king and pawn endgame, just knowing whether or not the pawn will queen is often the difference between a win and a loss, and this trick will save a lot of time, often during time pressure.
- **drawn bishop and rook pawn endgames** - again, if you know that a rook pawn and the wrong colored bishop will only draw, this will enable you to save time and half points.
- **drawn knight vs pawn endgames** - sometimes a lone knight can fight successfully against the enemy king and pawn, sometimes not.  At a certain level (1900+?) it's important to know when the king and pawn win and when they only draw.  That's probably a separate question on its own...

### Rook endgames

- **Lucena position** - the [Lucena position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucena_position) is the most common method of winning with a rook and extra pawn vs rook.  It's not terribly difficult to commit to memory either - spend 5-10 minutes and learn how to win when you get your king in front of your pawn!
- **Philidor position** - the [Philidor position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philidor_position) is the most common drawing method if you are down a pawn.  Again, doesn't take much time to learn the basic position, and a good investment if you want to save a few draws in your games.
- **cut off king** - if the enemy king can be cut off along a file or a rank, usually the stronger side will win.  However, learning the exceptions to this rule is important as well.  This is far less common than other winning rook endgames though, so less important if you just want practical knowledge.

### Piece relationships and domination

- **bishop dominates knight** - a picture is worth 1000 words...
  [image: Bishop dominates knight]
- **king dominates knight** - similar to king and pawn vs lone knight...
  [image: King dominates knight]

### More complicated endgames

- **queen endgames** - learning how to win with an extra pawn in a queen endgame can be valuable, as can learning how to defend.  There are few very common tricks (walking your king close to the enemy king to allow for cross-checks, deciding which corner to run to when you are on the weaker side, etc.) that are useful.  Again, this might be worth its own question.
- **bishops of opposite color** - many times bishops of opposite color are a quick draw.  Not always though!  Learning some of the patterns used to get a win with an extra pawn or two in this endgame will allow you to win as the stronger side, and avoid losing as the weaker side.  Common patterns/tricks include two pawns vs no pawns separated by a single file (many times a draw), learning how to win with two pawns separated by 3+ files (hint: king helps the pawn barricaded by the enemy bishop), and learning how to draw these positions.

### Tactics and mating patterns

Learning some basic mating patterns or typical tricks can be useful as well:

- **Greek gift Bxh7+ sacrifice** - if black doesn't have a knight on f6 and white has a knight on f3, queen on d1, and a bishop that is attacking h7, it's imperative to at least check this sacrifice.  The [Art of the Attack](http://books.google.com/books/about/Art_of_Attack.html?id=3euYQQAACAAJ) has a whole chapter dedicated to this common theme.
- **Checkmate patterns** - spend an hour learning patterns - the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate_pattern) is a great start, but [Art of the Checkmate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486201066) is the authoritative book and it is available fairly cheap on Amazon...

Well, that was a lot, please feel free to add or embellish this answer if you think of more patterns and tricks!

Comment: Brilliant answer. Lucena position, Philidor position, etc. Standard "wins" that aren't always won.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer.

Comment: What is a fork?

Answer (score 3):

Maximum distance between knight and any piece. Distance between king and passed pawns. Distance between knight and passed pawns (has to be calculated because the knight can give a check to gain time). Recognize opposite colored bishop endgames that can still be won (by blocking the opponent bishop diagonal or preventing the bishop from taking a diagonal using your king). Taking the seventh rank with your rook. Stopping enemy passed pawns with your rook. Blocking enemy passed pawns with a knight. Learn all endgame wins by heart (K+Q vs K, K+R vs K, K+Q vs K+R, K+B+B vs K, K+B+N vs K). Learn to use the R+N team to attack the enemy king. Also, I would advice to read and work with the book My System written by Nimzowitsch. It has a collection of ideas and goals that can guide you during the entire game.